# Given a desired width and font, how can I find the height of a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift

```
func calculateHeightOfLabel(text: String, width: CGFloat, font: UIFont){
    //how can I find the height of a UILabel with these properties ?
}
```

The UILabel might may have more than 1 line(s), and this function should take that into account.

I want to create a global helper function that can find the height (as if it was added to a view)

Comment: UILabel already has a method `sizeThatFits`. You can call it on any UILabel e.g. `let labelSize:CGSize = label.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width:someWidth,height:reallyBigNumber)`

Comment: Can I do this before adding it as a subview?

Comment: Yes. Also, if you just want the label's frame to be set to the bounds of the text you can just call `label.sizeToFit()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method which I used

```
func getSize(text: String, labelfont fontType: UIFont, width labelwidth: Float) -> CGSize {
text = "\(text)"
var font1: UIFont = fontType
var attributedText: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font1])
var rect: CGRect = attributedText.boundingRectWithSize(CGRect()
    rect.labelwidth
    rect.CGFLOAT_MAX, options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
var size: CGSize = rect.size
return size
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Swift

```
 func sizeWithAttributes(_ attrs: [String : AnyObject]?) ->
     CGSize
```

Objective-c

```
 - (CGSize)sizeWithAttributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> * nullable)attributes
```

Example:

```
func calculateHeightOfLabel(text: String, width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) {
       return text.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font]).height
}
```